# vimscript augment rtp with directory above result of system command

Tags: vim

I'm trying to modify my vimrc to include a directory

```
let g:mydir = system('which someExecutable')
execute "set rtp+=" . g:mydir
```

The problem is that `which someExecutable` returns something like
`/aDir/a/b`.
I need `g:mydir` set to `/aDir/`, so two dirs above `b`.

Is there an easy way to do this in vimscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `fnamemodify(path, ":h")`

If you version of vim is recent enough, you can even use `exepath('someExecutable')` instead of `system('which someexecutable')`. Which gives:

```
fnamemodify(exepath('someExecutable'), ":h")
```

PS: don't forget to escape what must be escaped if you use `exe "set rtp+=....`